# Why is the number 2 needed for 2-methylpropanal?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I think there is just one possible position for the methyl group to 'fit in' to propanal, however, my textbook and wiki suggests the correct names should be '2-methylpropanal'. Why is the '2' needed?

Comment: Related (concerning 2-methylpropanoic acid): [IUPAC rules on omission of locants in carboxylic acid](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/84004/7951)

Answer (score 1):

Well I suppose you are correct in a way- but it does help us see the molecule quicker in our heads...

it should be written methyl-2-propan-1-al or methyl-2-propan-2-al
otherwise it would be a butan-1-al  or butan-2-al

let me explain further>
the new IUPAC nomenclature  advises the use of numbers instead of the iso epithet- in organic chemistryIn old naming -as with propanol and iso-propanol - so with propanal

### Isopropyl alcohol

Preferred IUPAC name

### Propan-2-ol

-
Isopropyl alcohol (IUPAC name propan-2-ol; commonly called isopropanol) is a compound with the chemical formula C3H8O. -It is a structural isomer of 1-propanol.

wiki  Chemical Names: ISOBUTYRALDEHYDE; 2-Methylpropanal; 78-84-2; Isobutanal; Isobutylaldehyde; Propanal, 2-methyl- More... Molecular Formula: C4H8O or (CH3)2CHCHO.