# Why is it called N-Methylmethanamine?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

The IUPAC name of $(\text{CH}_3)_2\text{NH}$ is **N-Methylmethanamine** according to [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/#query=N-Methylmethanamine). Shouldn't the locant **N-** be dropped, given that there is no ambiguity over where the substitutent methyl may be located? (If it were attached to the carbon atom, the IUPAC name of the compound would be **Ethanamine**).

Comment: Related: [My answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/88150/101286) to a different question

Comment: I think we should always keep questions even if they seem related. If the question is duplicate then the community will mark it. If it's not duplicate I would humbly suggest that it shouldn't be deleted after being answered. This way firstly contributors earn rewards, secondly the people trying to search about related topics on the internet would be able to find an answer quickly.

Comment: @Desai That is my intuition too. However, it is beneficial for the community if questions have accepted answers. My question is more along the lines of, would Loong write an answer here or should I answer my own question with a link pointing to Loong's older answer.

Comment: You can do it yourself, just make sure that you credit @Loong properly with a link to the answer and a mention!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IUPAC rules on omission of locants in carboxylic acid](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/84004/iupac-rules-on-omission-of-locants-in-carboxylic-acid)

Answer (score -1):

It is according to IUPAC rules that while naming alkyl substituted amines, we add a prefix of N before it. In this case also, it is the same... nevertheless, your reasoning of no ambiguity over dropping the prefix N is correct, but the name would not be Methylmethanamine (incorrect), instead it would be dimethylamine which is also correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that dimethylamine is the common name for the compound, but my question was specifically _why_ Methylmethanamine is the wrong __IUPAC__ name.