# Why can't we say Dimethylbut-2-ene?

Tags: nomenclature

Considering the IUPAC rules state that you cannot extend the main chain and that carbon can only have 4 bonds, there is only one way to have two methyl groups on a but-2-ene. Therefore, why do we still keep the '2,3'?

Comment: Well, you just wrote that and I'm also pretty sure you can say it aloud ;)

Comment: Locants are only permitted to be omitted under very specific conditions, it isn't to do with logic or ambiguity: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/88150/16683

Comment: I'm glad that was useful. Hmm, I think we (the Chem.SE community) could make a more canonical Q&A for duplicates, though...