# What is the displayed formula for methylpropene?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am currently studying organic chemistry at school and I came across a question in my textbook which asked me to find the full displayed formula of methylpropene. I knew that there would be three carbons because of the 'prop' and that there would be a one-carbon side chain on the first carbon. However, in my chemistry textbook the one-carbon side chain is on the second carbon (the middle one). I don't know whether this is correct or not. Could someone please explain to me what the correct answer is?

Comment: There's only one place the methyl group can go for the compound to be a propene derivative i.e. the middle one. If you put it on the first carbon then it is a butene because you have a C4 chain; 1-Methyl-propene IS butene.

Comment: Related: [Naming of 2-methylpropane](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/51275/7951). Nevertheless, the name "methylpropene" is not in accordance with IUPAC nomenclature; see also [IUPAC rules on omission of locants in carboxylic acid](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/84004/7951)

Answer (score 1):

"Propene" is what defines the main chain of three atoms so that the maximum number of carbon atoms in *any other* chain cannot exceed this number. Hence your proposition that

> there would be a one-carbon side chain on the **first** carbon

is wrong as in this case there would be a 4-membered chain of either *1-butene* or *2‐butene*:

[image: 1-butene and 2‐butene]

In order to comply with the *methylpropene* name, one can only attach methyl group to the second carbon, and not to the terminal one:

[image: methylpropene]

To sum it up, your textbook is correct.